# Calculate an integral (quotient)

Tags: integration

*Calculate the following integral.*

$$\int\frac{5+2x+x^2}{x(x^2+1)}dx$$

I'm not sure what to do. Am I supposed to be using polynomial division?

Thanks.

Comment: Consider the method of partial fractions...  You could also start by separating it into pieces like $\dfrac {5+2x+x^2}{x(x^2+1)}=\dfrac {4+2x}{x(x^2+1)}+\dfrac {x^2+1}{x(x^2+1)}$...

Comment: Look at the degrees: do you need polynomial division?

Comment: No, the degree of the denominator is greater than the degree of the numerator. Write the integrand in the form $\displaystyle{A\over x}+{Bx+C\over x^2+1}$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html

Answer (score 1):

Write

$$\int \frac{5+2x+x^2}{x(x^2+1)} \text{d}x 
=
\int \frac{5}{x}\text{d}x - \int \frac{4x}{x^2+1}\text{d}x + \int \frac{2}{x^2+1}\text{d}x
$$

Can you do the rest?

Comment: Thanks! We got the exact same integrands as you, but we can't continue. We can calculate the first integrand to 5ln(abs(x)), but we can't calculate the other two.

Comment: What's the derivative of $\log f(x)$ for generic differentiable $f$?  What's the derivative of the arctan function?

Comment: Is log supposed to be the natural logarithm? If so, the derivative should be $\frac{1}{x}$. As for the arctan function, I have no idea.

Comment: @user133310 $\Big( \ln f(x) \Big)' = f'(x)/f(x)$ (why?)$ \implies \int f'(x)/ f(x) \ \text{d}x= \ln f(x) + C$ and for $\int \text{d}x/(x^2 + 1)$, let $x = \tan u$ and bear in mind that $\sec^2 x = \tan^2 x + 1$.